# Size of headings for a table with graphs

Tags: graphics, output-formatting, list-manipulation

I want to change the size of the heading of a table that includes graphs and am having no luck.

The command I am currently using is

```
GM = TableForm[GraphM,
TableHeadings -> {{"v=1", "v=.5", "v=.25", "v=.125"}, {"k=.4", "k=.2", "k=.1","k=.05"}},
TableAlignments -> Center,]
```

Where GraphM is a grid of plots generated with the command

```
GraphM = Table[Plot[{((4*k*(1 + a - a*k)*v)/(2 - 3*k*(1 + a - a*k))), (4*k*
   v/(2 - 3*k))}, {a, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> {1 -> Top, 2 -> Bottom} , 
AxesLabel -> {Style[\[Alpha]], Style[\[Beta]^2]}, 
AxesStyle -> Directive[11], Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500, 
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 500/25.}], {v, {1, 
 0.5, .25, .125}}, {k, {.4, .2, .1, .05}}];
```

the result is the following figure with almost unreadable headings.

[image]

I tried a variety of styling commands with no luck. Someone has a suggestion for me on how to make the table headings about the same size of the axes numbers?

Answer (score 3):

You can manually apply a style to each heading:

```
GM = TableForm[GraphM, 
  TableHeadings -> {{Style["v=1", FontSize -> 18], 
  Style["v=.5", FontSize -> 18], Style["v=.25", FontSize -> 18], 
  Style["v=.125", FontSize -> 18]}, {Style["k=.4", FontSize -> 18],
  Style["k=.2", FontSize -> 18], Style["k=.1", FontSize -> 18], 
  Style["k=.05", FontSize -> 18]}}, TableAlignments -> Center,]
```

Comment: Would've just commented this since it is an overly simple solution, but I need 50 rep :/

Comment: A little more concise would be `fonthead[s_] := Style[s, FontSize->18];` then apply that to each header

Comment: Thanks I had tried putting the style command on the outside of the {} but it did not work (i'm a bit of a rookie).